# rewriterule is not working with '/'

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following rewriterule code:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^about$ /about.php [QSA,L,NC]
RewriteRule ^about/mission$ /about_mission.php [QSA,L,NC]
RewriteRule ^about/team$ /about_team.php [QSA,L,NC]
RewriteRule ^about/join-me$ /about_join_me.php [QSA,L,NC]
```

On my local machine, it works perfectly, but on my server, only the page "about" is shown (even if i navigate to about/mission...). If I do the following:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^about$ /about.php [QSA,L,NC]
RewriteRule ^about-mission$ /about_mission.php [QSA,L,NC]
RewriteRule ^about-team$ /about_team.php [QSA,L,NC]
RewriteRule ^about-join-me$ /about_join_me.php [QSA,L,NC]
```

it works (when I navigate to "about-mission" the mission page shows up).

Anyone who has an idea what might be wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Add this to disable MultiViews:

```
Options -MultiViews
```

The [Apache docs on mod_negotiation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_negotiation.html), describes what the Multiviews Option does, when enabled:

> If the
>   server receives a request for /some/dir/foo and /some/dir/foo does not
>   exist, then the server reads the directory looking for all files named
>   foo.*, and effectively fakes up a type map which names all those
>   files, assigning them the same media types and content-encodings it
>   would have if the client had asked for one of them by name. It then
>   chooses the best match to the client's requirements, and returns that
>   document.